# Get the right domain name in Eureka on Docker

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

I am working with the Spring framework on a micro services architecture and i am using HTTPS with a self signed certificate (`*.mydomainname.fr`).
As registry I am using Eureka and as proxy I am using Zuul. So my services must be registered on Eureka with the name `"service-name".mydomainname.fr` because of my certificate. Also, I am not using a DNS for the moment, I am just adding the domain name manually in the `/etc/hosts` (`127.0.0.1 register.bec3.fr`). [Here my micro service architecture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIsBA.png)

I would like to dockerise all my services in a docker-compose.
My docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: '3'
services:
    registration-service:
        image: maven:alpine
        container_name: register.bec3.fr
        working_dir: /usr/src/spring-boot-app
        volumes:
         - ./scripts:/usr/src/spring-boot-app/scripts
         - ./sslcert:/usr/src/spring-boot-app/ssl
         - ./registration-service:/usr/src/spring-boot-app
         - ./.m2:/root/.m2
        expose: 
         - 8761
        entrypoint: bash -c "keytool -noprompt -import -alias ioteam.bec3 -file /usr/src/spring-boot-app/ssl/ioteam.pem -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass xxxxxx && mvn -Dspring.profiles.active=docker spring-boot:run"
        #entrypoint: bash -c "/usr/src/spring-boot-app/scripts/addhosts.sh && keytool -noprompt -import -alias ioteam.bec3 -file /usr/src/spring-boot-app/ssl/ioteam.pem -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass xxxxxx && mvn -Dspring.profiles.active=docker spring-boot:run"
        ports: 
         - 8761:8761
        networks: 
          back-net:
            ipv4_address: 172.20.0.5
            aliases:
              - register.bec3.fr
        depends_on:
         - "maria"

proxy-service:
    image: maven:alpine
    container_name: proxy.bec3.fr
    working_dir: /usr/src/spring-boot-app
    volumes:
     - ./scripts:/usr/src/spring-boot-app/scripts
     - ./sslcert:/usr/src/spring-boot-app/ssl
     - ./proxy-service:/usr/src/spring-boot-app
     - ./.m2:/root/.m2
    expose: 
     - 8888
    entrypoint: bash -c "keytool -noprompt -import -alias ioteam.bec3 -file /usr/src/spring-boot-app/ssl/ioteam.pem -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass xxxxxx && mvn -Dspring.profiles.active=docker spring-boot:run"
    #entrypoint: bash -c "/usr/src/spring-boot-app/scripts/addhosts.sh && keytool -noprompt -import -alias ioteam.bec3 -file /usr/src/spring-boot-app/ssl/ioteam.pem -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass xxxxxx && mvn -Dspring.profiles.active=docker spring-boot:run"
    ports: 
     - 8888:8888
    networks: 
      back-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.6
        aliases:
          - proxy.bec3.fr
    depends_on:
     - "registration-service"

auth-service:
    image: maven:alpine
    container_name: auth.bec3.fr
    working_dir: /usr/src/spring-boot-app
    volumes:
     - ./scripts:/usr/src/spring-boot-app/scripts
     - ./sslcert:/usr/src/spring-boot-app/ssl
     - ./auth-service:/usr/src/spring-boot-app
     - ./.m2:/root/.m2
    expose: 
     - 9999
    entrypoint: bash -c "keytool -noprompt -import -alias ioteam.bec3 -file /usr/src/spring-boot-app/ssl/ioteam.pem -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass xxxxxx && mvn -Dspring.profiles.active=docker spring-boot:run"
    #entrypoint: bash -c "/usr/src/spring-boot-app/scripts/addhosts.sh && keytool -noprompt -import -alias ioteam.bec3 -file /usr/src/spring-boot-app/ssl/ioteam.pem -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass xxxxxx && mvn -Dspring.profiles.active=docker spring-boot:run"
    ports: 
     - 9999:9999
    networks: 
      back-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.7
        aliases:
          - auth.bec3.fr
    depends_on:
     - "maria"
     - "registration-service"

maria:
    build:
        context: ./
        dockerfile: maria-dev/Dockerfile
    image: maria:latest
    container_name: maria
    environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
    networks:
      back-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.3

networks:
  back-net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
     config:
     - subnet: 172.20.0.0/24
```

So my services can registered to my register service because of that parameter in my application.propertise:

```
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=https://register.bec3.fr:8761/eureka/
```

My problem is when I am launching those services there names are the docker ID on my eureka dashboard:

- 72959axxxxx:auth:9999
- c0f1c4xxxxx:proxy:8888

[My eureka service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaYPK.png)

and I need something like that :

- auth.mydomainname.fr:auth:9999
- proxy.mydomainname.fr:proxy:8888

Because of my certificate. Without that I cannot reach my services with a cURL:

```
curl -i -XPOST "https://web_app:@register.bec3.fr:8888/auth/oauth/token" -d "grant_type=password&username=toto&password=toto" --cacert my-cert.crt
```

What can I do ? Can I use a custom hostname in Eureka or should I change my Docker configuration?
Thank you, for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. It was for a proof of concept so the way i solved it, was a bit dirty.

Actually you get that 72959axxxxx:auth:9999 in your eureka dashboard and you need auth.mydomainname.fr:auth:9999.

The solution is to add at the top of your /etc/hosts in the docker of your service the domain name of this service. Try to do it with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOSTS="/etc/hosts"
TMP1="tmp1"
TMP2="tmp2"
IP="192.168.1.1"
DN="domainenameservice"

SERVICE="$IP\t$DN"

echo -e $SERVICE > $TMP1
cat $TMP1 $HOSTS > $TMP2

echo "# test" > $HOSTS
while IFS= read -r var
do
  echo "$var" >> $HOSTS
done < $TMP2
```